# need help installing drush on mac

Tags: terminal, composer-php, drush

I'm on a mac. And I user MAMP a lot. I'm pretty new to command line and I'm trying to install Drush. I see I need to install composer first (according to what I read at drush-ops, so I did. Here's the commands I put in:

```
my-MacBook-Pro:~ mycomputername$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /Users/myname/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
my-MacBook-Pro:~ mycomputername$  mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: Permission denied
my-MacBook-Pro:~ mycomputername$ sudo  mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
Password:
```

after which I did a command "composer about" to check and I got something back so I know it installed. so when i entered:

```
my-MacBook-Pro:~ mycomputername$ composer global require drush/drush:6.*
Changed current directory to /Users/myname/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

- Installing drush/drush (6.2.0)
    Downloading: 100%

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

...and did a "drush status" I got:

```
my-MacBook-Pro:~ mycomputername$ drush status
-bash: drush: command not found
```

...so apparently it installed but I should be able to find it. What should I do next? do i need to create and alias or what?

Answer (score 2):

When running `drush status` you should get something like this

```
PHP executable        :  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php      
PHP configuration     :  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf/php.ini 
PHP OS                :  Darwin                                            
Drush version         :  6.2.0                                             
Drush configuration   :                                                    
Drush alias files     :
```

I installed drush doing just this command

```
brew install drush
```

Brew is very helpful to install things in command line, I recommend you install [brew](http://brew.sh/).
[(http://brew.sh/)](http://brew.sh/)

Comment: I followed your suggestion and it worked I get Drush although my drush status is a little different maybe due to where it installed. Instead I got:
 PHP executable        :  /usr/bin/php 
 PHP configuration     :               
 PHP OS                :  Darwin       
 Drush version         :  6.2.0        
 Drush configuration   :               
 Drush alias files     :   

Will there be a problem?
(thanks)

Comment: No problem at all. The difference is that my `drush status` referenced the php on MAMP, because I was on MAMP. Your status referenced the php installed in your computer. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler answer! Just quote the version string :) You don't need to switch to Brew from Composer.

```
composer global require "drush/drush:7.*"
```

Here's more info about using Composer to manage Drush...
http://whaaat.com/installing-drush-8-using-composer

Answer (score 0):

1. Download drush.tar.gz to your desktop (or wherever)
2. Jump across to the Terminal
   cd ~/Desktop
3. Extract it with
   tar -zxf drush.tar.gz
4. Move it to /usr/local/lib
   sudo mv drush /usr/local/lib/
5. Make it executable
   sudo chmod u+x /usr/local/lib/drush/drush
6. Then stick it in /usr/bin/ so that you can run it from anywhere
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/drush/drush /usr/bin/drush